# Xbox 360 apps cannot connect to Xbox Live

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

When I try to play Netflix or YouTube, my Xbox 360 errors out saying it needs a connection to Xbox Live.

However, "Test Xbox Live Connection" Shows that

1. It can connect to Network
2. It can connect to Internet
3. It can connect to Xbox Live

Not sure why it errors when I play or use an application. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried:

1. Using Ethernet instead of WiFi
2. Restarting the Console
3. Restarting the router and modem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have this same problem when it comes to certain arcade games, Castle Crashers for example.

I found out the problem was the account I was using, for some reason it just wouldn't work. So, I made a new account for specific things and bravo it worked. Don't bother talking to xbox support, they said my account should be working fine, yet... It wasn't. So yeah, try another account.